# Electric scooter

Tags: pcb, brushless-dc-motor, controller

my daughter has trouble depressing the switch on the board to make the scooter go, is there anyway I can wire a throttle to this controller, I can't find the wireing diagram for it so I'm stuck, any help would be amazing.[image]

Comment: that looks like a connector to me

Answer (score 0):

As there are 3 wires, it may be a analog input, able to be wired to a potentiometer, if so you may be able to buy a throttle from another scooter and retrofit it to your one,

You can test this by using some resistance, e.g. 10K between the red / white or white / black wires and seeing if it makes the motor spin, if it does you may be in luck.

Comment: I'll give it a go, I have a thumb throttle red black and green wires I put red with red black with black and green with white but nothing, when you say a 10k resistance (sorry I'm new to all this)  you mean put a 10k resistor (I think i have) between the two?, out of interest why a resistor not just a bit of wire.

Comment: I was thinking a resistor as without knowing what the circuit does, it was a safer call than shorting out ransom wires when a battery is involved. You pointed to a "switch" connector that seems to go to some kind of optocoupler, so I expect its switching to ground, e.g. white to black, but felt I would play it safe with so little information

Comment: OK so red/white it turns on, black/white nothing and black/red nothing, so where would you wire the red green black wires too off the throttle? Iv tried different combos wire to wire but nothing when I press the throttle down

Comment: Ok, if red/white turns it on, e.g. makes the motor spin, then we would need to know what throttle your using, with any luck it may be a PWM output which seems to be how I would imagine you controlling the speed if its otherwise just a stop / go switch. by switching the "go" on and off X% you get an average throttle amount (still odd that a scooter would only have a "go" button

Comment: The throttle is Just a standard  cheapo (amazon) uses a magnet coming close over some component looking thing (very technical) tbh might only be an on/off set speed due to it being for kids, it never had speed adjustment on it. Will just have to add a momentary switch up by the handle to pulse it like I'm assuming it used to do, iv ordered another controller off amazon with the correct wires coming out (black green red) for the throttle see what happens, I'm assuming this ones cheap cheap and bullet proof.